# mybatis return result map with duplicate entry

Tags: mybatis

I am using mybatis to retrieve data from DB, the data returned is containing duplicate entries.

Required result : Column Name , Value

Expected result is : column1 value A 
But returned result is : COLUMN1 value A , column1 value A.

Hope able to clarify my doubt.

Can anybody tell me why it is happening?

```
<select id="getContentMap" resultType="map" parameterType="map">
            select planId,location_qualifier  from disclaimer_disclosure_content where 
            <choose>
                <when test="plan_id != null">
                    plan_id = #{plan_id}
                </when>
                <when test="product_id != null">
                    product_id = #{product_id}
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    issuer_id = #{issuer_id}
                </otherwise>
            </choose>
             and effective_date >= #{effective_date} 
             and location_qualifier LIKE  CONCAT('%' , #{location_qualifier} , '%') 
        </select>
```

Comment: Can you post your Table Structure and Query.??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is a bug in MyBatis 3 up until release 3.0.6:  http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=303.

After that release you get the answer I outlined in my other answer (which was done with MyBatis 3.1.1).

You have four options:

1. Just ignore it and only grab the uppercase or lowercase entries
2. Upgrade to at least 3.0.6
3. Stop using map as resultType and move to a POJO domain object
4. Use the workaround below:

#### workaround for MyBatis < 3.0.6

Use full uppercase column aliases and they will only show up once (as uppercase) in your map:

```
<select id="getContentMap" resultType="map" parameterType="map">
  select plan_id as PLAN_ID, location_qualifier as LOCATION_QUALIFIER from disclaimer_disclosure_content
  where
  <!-- SNIP: is the same as you had -->
</select>
```

This results in the output:

```
{PLAN_ID=2, LOCATION_QUALIFIER=Bar}
```

(or something similar depending on exactly how your select looks).

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to report more information, such as:

1. what database are you using?
2. what version of MyBatis 3 are you using (or are you still using iBATIS)?
3. what does your table structure look like?

In any case, I tried out a slightly simplified version of your query using MySQL 5.1 and MyBatis-3.1.1 and it worked fine - meaning that I only got back one entry of the column name in the result map.  I provide my setup below so you can try to reproduce it or diagnose where your code may be wrong.

First, you have a error in your select statement.  You have

```
SELECT planId
```

but then you have:

```
WHERE ... plan_id = #{plan_id}
```

so you probably meant `SELECT plan_id` in the SELECT clause.

Here is what worked for me.

My slightly simplified MyBatis select mapping is:

```
<select id="getContentMap" resultType="map" parameterType="map">
  SELECT plan_id, location_qualifier FROM disclaimer_disclosure_content
  WHERE
  <choose>
    <when test="plan_id != null">
      plan_id = #{plan_id}
    </when>
    <otherwise>
     product_id = #{product_id}
    </otherwise>
  </choose>
  AND location_qualifier LIKE CONCAT('%' , #{location_qualifier} , '%')
</select>
```

Second, my MySQL table for this query:

```
mysql> select * from disclaimer_disclosure_content;
+---------+--------------------+------------+
| plan_id | location_qualifier | product_id |
+---------+--------------------+------------+
|       1 | Foo                |        101 |
|       2 | Bar                |        102 |
|       3 | Baz                |        103 |
|       4 | Quux               |        104 |
+---------+--------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Third, my Java code to use the mapping:

```
@Test
public void testForSO() throws Exception {
  Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  paramMap.put("plan_id", 2);
  paramMap.put("location_qualifier", "Ba");

  List<Map<String,Object>> lmap = session.selectList("getContentMap", paramMap);
  assertNotNull(lmap);
  Map<String,Object> m = lmap.get(0);
  assertNotNull(m);
  System.out.println(m.toString());
}
```

This passes and prints out:

```
{location_qualifier=Bar, plan_id=2}
```

I also tried it with

```
Map<String,Object> m = session.selectOne("getContentMap", paramMap);
```

and get the same expected result.

Comment: we using mybatis version 3.0 , mysql as db 5.1.12 .

Comment: OK. I did some research on the earlier versions of MyBatis - this is a bug in earlier versions of Mybatis. See my new answer for details and a workaround.